# Why won't pySerial write inside of my program?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

So I have a program set up on my arduino nano which reads a single byte from the serial port and turns on an LED depending on whether or not the byte received was 1 or 0. I thoroughly tested this program, both on the Serial monitor and with pySerial in the python 3 shell, and it worked fine. But when I have a simple program like this:

```py
import serial
SERIAL = serial.Serial("COM4", 9600)
SERIAL.write(b'1')
```

The board doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong that pySerial works in the python shell but not in a python program?

Comment: When you say "1 or 0", do you mean the numeric values 1 or 0, or the ASCII characters '1' or '0'?  Those aren't the same thing...

Comment: The program on the arduino reads the 1 or 0 as a char and converts the ASCII to ints. Again, I got it to work through the python shell, but when I put the exact same code into the program it did nothing.

Comment: Port still open? I don't see it being closed anywhere.  Also look for differences in environment.  I can run stuff in my venv in Pycharm that will not run from the console without being packaged.

Comment: the arduino resets on new USB connection and spends a second in bootloader waiting for upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you open the serial port, delay it for minimum a second, because the Arduino resets itself when you open the serial connection and doesn't start reading from the serial immediately.

Example:

```
import serial
import time
SERIAL = serial.Serial(baudrate='115200', timeout=.2, port='com4') #this edit is not important
time.sleep(3) #sleep 3 seconds
SERIAL.write(b'1')
```